# C: thread safety and order of operations

Tags: c, thread-safety

Consider the following C code:

```
static sig_atomic_t x;
static sig_atomic_t y;

int foo()
{
    x = 1;
    y = 2;
}
```

First question: can the C compiler decide to "optimize" the code for `foo` to `y = 2; x = 1` (in the sense that the memory location for `y` is changed before the memory location for `x`)? This would be equivalent, except when multiple threads or signals are involved.

If the answer to the first question is "yes": what should I do if I really want the guarantee that `x` is stored before `y`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the compiler may change the order of the two assignments, because the reordering is not "observable" *as defined by the C standard*, e.g., there are no side-effects to the assignments (again, as defined by the C standard, which does not consider the existence of an outside observer).

In practice you need some kind of barrier/fence to guarantee the order, e.g., use the services provided by your multithreading environment, or possibly C11 `stdatomic.h` if available.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard specifies a term called *observable behavior*. This means that at a minimum, the compiler/system has a few restrictions: it is not allowed to re-order expressions containing `volatile`-qualified operands, nor is it allowed to re-order input/output.

Apart from those special cases, anything is fair game. It may execute y before x, it may execute them in parallel. It might optimize the whole code away as there are no observable side-effects in the code. And so on.

Please note that thread-safety and order of execution are different things. Threads are created explicitly by the programmer/libraries. A context switch may interrupt any variable acccess which is not atomic. That's another issue and the solution is to use mutex, `_Atomic` qualifier or similar protection mechanisms.

---

If the order matters, you should `volatile`-qualify the variables. In that case, the following guarantees are made by the language:

C17 5.1.2.3 § 6 (the definition of observable behavior):

> Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.

C17 5.1.2.3 § 4:

> In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics.

Where "semantics" is pretty much the whole standard, for example the part that specifies that a `;` consists of a sequence point. (In this case, C17 6.7.6 "The end of a full
declarator is a sequence point." The term "sequenced before" is specified in C17 5.1.2.3 §3).

So given this:

```
volatile int x = 1;
volatile int y = 1;
```

then the order of initialization is guaranteed to be x before y, as the `;` of the first line guarantees the sequencing order, and `volatile` guarantees that the program strictly follows the evaluation order specified in the standard.

---

Now as it happens in the real world, `volatile` does not guarantee memory barriers on many compiler implementations for multi-core systems. Those implementations are not conforming.

Opportunist compilers might claim that the programmer must use system-specific memory barriers to guarantee order of execution. But in case of `volatile`, that is not true, as proven above. They just want to dodge their responsibility and hand it over to the programmers. The C standard doesn't care if the CPU has 57 cores, branch prediction and instruction pipelining.

Comment: An operation on a `volatile` does not (have to) set a memory barrier because concurrent read/write access is undefined.

Comment: @LWimsey I just cited all over this answer why it concurrent _execution_ is well-defined. Sequencing is defined in C17 5.1.2.3 §3. Concurrent access of data memory is another story. The purpose of memory barriers is to guarantee order of execution, not to guarantee thread-safety of data. If you use the `volatile` keyword, then implementing memory barriers correctly in the underlying machine code is the C compiler's job.

Comment: Your quotes are about evaluation order on `volatile` objects. The compiler must ensure they are evaluated according to the rules of the abstact machine, but that does not mean the effects of those operations are observed by other threads in the same order. In fact, reasoning about ordering with respect to other threads is meaningless because `volatile` does not make an object data-race-free.  I am not sure though how you see the difference between "_concurrent execution is well-defined_" and then "_Concurrent access of data memory is another story_", but concurrent read/write access ....

Comment: .... on a non-atomic object is undefined behavior per C17 5.1.2.4 §35:
_The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior._
Since operations on `volatile` objects are only well-defined within a single thread (without additional synchronization), memory barriers are not involved. Microsoft compilers have used memory barriers on `volatile` operations, but that is based on a stronger guarantee than necessary.

Comment: @LWimsey What I mean is that order of execution per thread is well-defined. If the compiler were to parallelize execution so that it get executed by multiple cores - which the C standard does not inhibit - it must still follow the rules of the abstract machine. This includes things like instruction caching, branch prediction and pipeline execution.

Comment: @LWimsey You are talking about "concurrent access on a non-atomic object" but that's not what my question is about. One can get atomicity for assignment by using the type sig_atomic_t (I'll edit the question). My question is about the order of the 2 assignments.

Comment: @JeroenDemeyer In your example, the 2 assignments are obviously carried out by the same thread, which is addressed by this answer and _not_ thread-safety. I guess I have no idea what you are asking for.

Comment: @JeroenDemeyer You are right, but it came up because memory barriers were mentioned

Comment: @Lundin That the execution order per thread is well-defined is a given.. If a CPU could not see its own stores right away, it would be practically impossible to program