# temporary volatile using casts

Tags: c, casting, volatile

Some C library function omit warnings via the compiler when `volatile` values are passed to them; for example `memcpy()`.
Now I wondered whether I could use some `volatile` casts to enforce immediate evaluation.
Consider:

```c
int b; /* ... */
(volatile int) b = 1;
b = (volatile int) 1;
```

Now does the second line cause immediate assignment to `b`, and does the third line do the same?
Or can't a constant like `1` be made "more volatile" (meaning it won't have any effect)?

Comment: `(volatile int) b = 1` creates a temporary, an rvalue. You can't assign to that. Perhaps `*((volatile int*)&b) = 1;` would make a difference. You'd better check the assembly.

Comment: Immediate as in what, an immediate assembler instruction or just English "immediately"?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, I cannot assign to that, but the expression will yield a "volatile" value that's being ignored. But the side-effect should be that the instruction is not moved around by the compiler, I guessed.

Comment: @Lundin Just imagine there are many other instruction before and after that statement (as suggested by `/* ... */`). Immediate should mean that the compiler does not move the statement around, meaning it's evaluated *after* the instructions before were executed, and the instructions after that are executed - well - after that statement.

Comment: "_but the expression will yield a "volatile" value_" - I don't see it since it will not compile.

Comment: Hmm. I had a `if ((volatile int) b == 0) ...` that compiled with gcc-4.8.5. So I assumed `(volatile int) b` would be a valid expression, too. Sorry that I had mis-typed `volatile` in my question. OK, I might have mixed *reading* and *writing*...

Comment: @U.Windl It's complicated. If reading the (unhelpfully vague) C standard strictly, `volatile` should act as a memory barrier. In practical implementations, it does not always do that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53416572/584518

Comment: Also... fun fun, while writing an answer I think I just found a bug in gcc 11.

Comment: For those interested I posted a question about the bug here: [Non-conforming optimizations of volatile in gcc 11.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70380510/non-conforming-optimizations-of-volatile-in-gcc-11-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualifiers (`const`, `restrict`, `volatile`, and `_Atomic`) never apply to values. They only apply to objects, because they tell the compiler something about how to handle the memory of an object.

So `(volatile int) b` and `(volatile int) 1` have no effect different from `(int) b` and `(int) 1`.

You can access a non-volatile object with a volatile lvalue, as with `* (volatile int *) &x = value;`. Then the C implementation must access the object (read or write it) strictly according to the semantics of C’s abstract machine. It may be reordered with other non-volatile expressions generally but not with observable behaviors: accessing volatile objects, interactive I/O, and writing to files.