# Is gcc optimizing out my wait code, despite marking it volatile?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, inline-assembly, volatile

On a STM32 ARM Cortex M4, I have a simple bare metal blinky which strobes a LED on.  It works fine when I use a spin wait:

```
typedef volatile uint32_t vuint32_t;
#define SET(addr, bits) (*((vuint32_t*) (addr)) |= (bits))
#define CLR(addr, bits) (*((vuint32_t*) (addr)) &= ~(bits))

for (;;) {
  SET(GPIOA+_ODR, BIT(5));
  // spin(100);
  for (volatile int i = 100 * 1000; i; --i) asm("nop");
  CLR(GPIOA+_ODR, BIT(5));
  //spin(1000);
  for (volatile int i = 1000 * 1000; i; --i) asm("nop");
}
```

The above code works perfectly - it strobes the LED on periodically.  And, if I uncomment **one** of the `spin()` calls, and comment out the corresponding `for` call, it also works well.  But if I use `spin()` for both, the light is **reversed**: it is mainly ***on***, and blinks ***off***.

Using `gdb`, it seems like it is switching around the order of the calls (or otherwise executing them differently than expected).  I can't figure out why it does this, though, since I have everything marked volatile:

```
void spin(uint32_t ms) {
  uint32_t ticks = (CPU_HZ / 1000) * ms;
  (*(vuint32_t*) (STK+_LOAD)) = ticks - 1;
  SET((STK+_CTRL), (BIT(2) | BIT(0)));
  while (! ((*(vuint32_t*) STK+_CTRL) & COUNTFLAG)) asm volatile("nop");
}
```

The macros like `GPIOA`, `STK`, and `_LOAD` are because I'm doing this bare metal, no external libs.  But I've tested them and they all work well under isolation.  The cause seems to be that the compiler is changing the order (or omitting?).  I was able to confirm this using `objdump`, at least some of the time.

I'm using `arm-none-eabi-gcc 10.3.1`.  See also: [Non-conforming optimizations of volatile in gcc 11.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70380510/non-conforming-optimizations-of-volatile-in-gcc-11-1).

---

## Updates:

With only one call to `spin`, `spin(100)` acts as expected, `spin(1000)` acts as expected, but **`spin(5000)` seems to only spin for 1 second** (as far as I can time).

I'm using `-Os`.  Switching to `-O0` does not solve the problem.

---

As requested, here is the disassembly of `spin`. Note that, as per the suggestions, I've tried various changes, none of which behave as expected - below is the current one.

```
void spin(uint32_t ms) {
 80001ac:       b480            push    {r7}
 80001ae:       b085            sub     sp, #20
 80001b0:       af00            add     r7, sp, #0
 80001b2:       6078            str     r0, [r7, #4]
        uint32_t ticks = (CPU_HZ / 1000) * ms;
 80001b4:       687b            ldr     r3, [r7, #4]
 80001b6:       f44f 527a       mov.w   r2, #16000      ; 0x3e80
 80001ba:       fb02 f303       mul.w   r3, r2, r3
 80001be:       60fb            str     r3, [r7, #12]
        (*(vuint32_t*) (STK+_LOAD)) = ticks - 1;  // The -1 is necessary as per.
 80001c0:       4a11            ldr     r2, [pc, #68]   ; (8000208 <spin+0x5c>)
 80001c2:       68fb            ldr     r3, [r7, #12]
 80001c4:       3b01            subs    r3, #1
 80001c6:       6013            str     r3, [r2, #0]
    (*(vuint32_t*)(STK+_VAL)) = 0;
 80001c8:       4b10            ldr     r3, [pc, #64]   ; (800020c <spin+0x60>)
 80001ca:       2200            movs    r2, #0
 80001cc:       601a            str     r2, [r3, #0]
        SET(STK + _CTRL, BIT(2) | BIT(0));             // Enable SysTick @CPU_HZ
 80001ce:       4b10            ldr     r3, [pc, #64]   ; (8000210 <spin+0x64>)
 80001d0:       681b            ldr     r3, [r3, #0]
 80001d2:       4a0f            ldr     r2, [pc, #60]   ; (8000210 <spin+0x64>)
 80001d4:       f043 0305       orr.w   r3, r3, #5
 80001d8:       6013            str     r3, [r2, #0]
        CLR((STK+_CTRL), (BIT(16)));
 80001da:       4b0d            ldr     r3, [pc, #52]   ; (8000210 <spin+0x64>)
 80001dc:       681b            ldr     r3, [r3, #0]
 80001de:       4a0c            ldr     r2, [pc, #48]   ; (8000210 <spin+0x64>)
 80001e0:       f423 3380       bic.w   r3, r3, #65536  ; 0x10000
 80001e4:       6013            str     r3, [r2, #0]
        while (! ((*(vuint32_t*) STK+_CTRL) & COUNTFLAG)) asm("");
 80001e6:       e7ff            b.n     80001e8 <spin+0x3c>
 80001e8:       4b09            ldr     r3, [pc, #36]   ; (8000210 <spin+0x64>)
 80001ea:       681b            ldr     r3, [r3, #0]
 80001ec:       f403 3380       and.w   r3, r3, #65536  ; 0x10000
 80001f0:       2b00            cmp     r3, #0
 80001f2:       d0f9            beq.n   80001e8 <spin+0x3c>
        (*(vuint32_t*) (STK+_CTRL)) = 0;
 80001f4:       4b06            ldr     r3, [pc, #24]   ; (8000210 <spin+0x64>)
 80001f6:       2200            movs    r2, #0
 80001f8:       601a            str     r2, [r3, #0]
}
 80001fa:       bf00            nop
 80001fc:       3714            adds    r7, #20
 80001fe:       46bd            mov     sp, r7
 8000200:       f85d 7b04       ldr.w   r7, [sp], #4
 8000204:       4770            bx      lr
 8000206:       bf00            nop
 8000208:       e000e014        .word   0xe000e014
 800020c:       e000e018        .word   0xe000e018
 8000210:       e000e010        .word   0xe000e010
```

and of relevant portions of `main`:

```
08000214 <main>:

int main(void) {
...
    SET((GPIOA + _ODR), BIT(5));
 8000262:       4b0e            ldr     r3, [pc, #56]   ; (800029c <main+0x88>)
 8000264:       681b            ldr     r3, [r3, #0]
 8000266:       4a0d            ldr     r2, [pc, #52]   ; (800029c <main+0x88>)
 8000268:       f043 0320       orr.w   r3, r3, #32
 800026c:       6013            str     r3, [r2, #0]
    spin(100);
 800026e:       2064            movs    r0, #100        ; 0x64
 8000270:       f7ff ff9c       bl      80001ac <spin>
    //for (volatile int i = 1000 * 1000; i; --i) asm("nop");
    CLR((GPIOA + _ODR), BIT(5));
 8000274:       4b09            ldr     r3, [pc, #36]   ; (800029c <main+0x88>)
 8000276:       681b            ldr     r3, [r3, #0]
 8000278:       4a08            ldr     r2, [pc, #32]   ; (800029c <main+0x88>)
 800027a:       f023 0320       bic.w   r3, r3, #32
 800027e:       6013            str     r3, [r2, #0]
    spin(10000);
 8000280:       f242 7010       movw    r0, #10000      ; 0x2710
 8000284:       f7ff ff92       bl      80001ac <spin>
    SET((GPIOA + _ODR), BIT(5));
 8000288:       e7eb            b.n     8000262 <main+0x4e>
 800028a:       bf00            nop
...
 800029c:       40020014        .word   0x40020014
...
```

Comment: I would suggest using STM CMSIS headers. All definitions are there and your program will still be bare metal.

Comment: Is `vuint32_t` a typedef for `volatile uint32_t`?

Comment: Have you tried different numbers for the `spin` arg to see if the time varies the way you expect, like `500` and `250` blinks in a 2:1 duty cycle and faster than your current code?  Have you tried compiling with optimization disabled (the default `-O0` in GCC or clang)?  Compilers definitely won't reorder statements at `-O0`, so if you still see something unexpected then, it's not an optimization problem.  (Except perhaps within a single statement, but I think your statements are all relativesly simple.)

Comment: What's the point of `asm("nop")`?  Your loops already have volatile variables to force load/store asm instructions to be emitted.  (even accessing `i` multiple times, once to check it for 0, and separately to decrement since `--i` isn't the loop condition.)

Comment: I was going to ask if `uint32_ticks` could overflow (or is that `uint32 ticks`?), but 0___________ just posted an answer that would explain things if it's correct (I have no reason to doubt it; I don't know details of this platform or what MMIO registers your code is accessing.)  The fact that it still doesn't work at `-O0` is very strong evidence that it's not an optimization problem.  GCC does *not* reorder code between C statements at `-O0`, or even keep any variable values in registers between statements.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the disassembly of the for loop. Then we can instantly see if the compiler is doing something wrong.

Comment: @SRobertJames if you do not know how to include header files I would suggest improving your C language skills before bare metal programming.

Comment: The loop is there `beq.n   80001e8 <spin+0x3c>` so it wasn't optimized away. And it loads the value before comparing. It's some position-independent code so its a bit hard to read, but ldr in relation to pc should mean that it reads from some fixed memory address.

Comment: What is your clock speed `CPU_HZ`? The systick on ST32 is a 24-bit counter. If you are running at 32 MHz or faster, you are overflowing the load register.

Comment: @B.Pantalone 16 MHz

Comment: Then that's the problem.   16000x5000 > 24 bits.     You can only do 1048ms before overflowing.   No idea why ST decided 24 bits would be a good idea, though.

Comment: (FWIW, it's defined that way by ARM.   TIL.   Seems like saving those 8 bits of register makes more problems than it solves, but maybe that's important for keeping a critical path and upping the max MHz)

Comment: Cool, glad you were able to sort this out.  But please post answers as answers, not edits to the question.  I'd recommend reverting the question edit so it's still just a question, and posting the new section as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not blame compiler!!
`spin` function is wrong. You need reset the COUNTFLAG before your while loop (you can do this by writing to VAL register too).

```
#define SCS_BASE            (0xE000E000UL)                            
#define SysTick_BASE        (SCS_BASE +  0x0010UL) 
#define SysTick             ((SysTick_Type   *)     SysTick_BASE  ) 

#define     __IM     volatile const      /*! Defines 'read only' structure member permissions */
#define     __OM     volatile            /*! Defines 'write only' structure member permissions */
#define     __IOM    volatile            /*! Defines 'read / write' structure member permissions */


typedef struct
{
  __IOM uint32_t CTRL;                   /*!< Offset: 0x000 (R/W)  SysTick Control and Status Register */
  __IOM uint32_t LOAD;                   /*!< Offset: 0x004 (R/W)  SysTick Reload Value Register */
  __IOM uint32_t VAL;                    /*!< Offset: 0x008 (R/W)  SysTick Current Value Register */
  __IM  uint32_t CALIB;                  /*!< Offset: 0x00C (R/ )  SysTick Calibration Register */
} SysTick_Type;


void spin(uint32_t ms) 
{
    SysTick -> LOAD = (CPU_HZ / 1000) * ms - 1;
    
    SysTick->VAL   = 0UL;                                             
    SysTick->CTRL  = (1 << 0) | (1 << 2)
    whille(!(SysTick -> CTRL & (1 << 16)));
    SysTick->CTRL = 0;
}
```

Generated code:

```
spin:
        mov     r3, #8000
        mov     r2, #-536813568
        mul     r0, r3, r0
        subs    r0, r0, #1
        movs    r1, #0
        movs    r3, #5
        str     r0, [r2, #20]
        str     r1, [r2, #24]
        str     r3, [r2, #16]
.L2:
        ldr     r3, [r2, #16]
        lsls    r3, r3, #15
        bpl     .L2
        movs    r3, #0
        str     r3, [r2, #16]
        bx      lr
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5rbndcv1e

Comment: Yes, I configured systick via `SET(STK+_CTRL, BIT(2) | BIT(0))`.

Comment: You forgot about VAL register (me too as your code is very difficult to read)

Comment: According to ST document PM0214, writing to the STK_VAL register clears the count flag. It does not say writing to STK_LOAD clears it.

Comment: Confirming that clearing VAL is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what B.Pantalone says about the `SYSTICK` register being 24 bit (confirmed here https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0552/a/cortex-m3-peripherals/system-timer--systick/systick-current-value-register), and `CPU_MHZ` being 16MHz, the `spin()` function will silently overflow on any input value greater than 1047. (`(1<<24)/16000 = 1048`)

So, that's the root of your issue.

You can solve it in several ways (I'd suggest rewriting `spin()` to do something like:

```
void Spin(int ms)
{
  while(ms>1000)
  {
     spin(1000);
     ms -= 1000;
  } 
  spin(ms);
}
```

Comment: Confirming that there was an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

There were **3 different issues** here, which made this hard to debug:

1. As "0___" writes, I needed to clear `STK_VAL`, setting it to `0`, each time.  Without this, the `spin` worked the first time, but not (necessarily?) afterwards.
2. As B. Pantalone and Russ Scholtz write, SysTick is limited to 24 bits (about 1000ms in this case), causing an overflow.  This did not affect my original code, but only came up when I tried making the `ms` val several seconds in an attempt to debug (which of course made debugging quite confusing).
3. Finally, at one point, gcc had optimized out some of my code.  The cause is that gcc may eliminate a `asm("nop")` (even at `-O0`???).  It will not eliminate, however, a `asm("")`, nor will it eliminate a `asm volatile("nop")`.  I was not aware of this distinction, and so sometimes wrote `asm("nop")` but sometimes just `asm("")`, causing unexpected behavior.

This is a great example of how tricky debugging can be, esp. on an embedded platform. Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: Point 3 is not plausible unless there's a bug in GCC.  `asm("nop")` is implicitly `volatile`.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html .  And since you're using a GCC version >= 7, `asm("nop")` is equivalent to `asm volatile("nop" ::: "memory")` since GCC7 gave non-empty Basic Asm statements an implicit "memory" clobber.  (This is undocumented, and wouldn't matter anyway since any non-`volatile` loop counter wouldn't be affected by a "memory" clobber if you haven't taken its address.)

Comment: Not that this should matter, the `asm("nop")` statements in your code just make your loops *slightly* longer.  `volatile int i` loop counters already result in store/reload and a loop that can't be optimized away.  If you had other loops with non-`volatile` loop counters, then perhaps they could be optimized away, but even `asm("")` should prevent that, being implicitly `volatile`, unless GCC fully unrolls the loop and then does a million empty strings...  Which `asm("nop")` would prevent, since even if GCC is counting asm bytes as a rough cost estimate, it would see it doesn't want 1M nops.

Comment: BTW, generally don't use Basic Asm: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended  Use Extended to be more explicit about what you mean, or just don't use asm at all.