Microchip Studio: Could not read memory content for stack variable
I have a problem when debugging a firmware.
I work with Microchip Studio Version 7.0.2594 and a microcontroller called "ATSAME54P19A".
I can build the software without any warnings and errors. I can put the software on the controller without errors or warnings. I can start on chip debug over an Atmel ICE adapter and set breakpoints. But when I want to read a variable after the programm stops at the breakpoint, then I get the message "Could not read memory content for stack variable".
This message is only displayed in the include files. If I debug in the main itself, I can read the value of a variable.
Short example:
#include <utils.h>
#include <atmel_start.h>

#include "Anyinclude.h"

int main(void)
{
    volatile uint32_t testvariable __attribute__((unused)) = 0;

    atmel_start_init();

   testvariable = 5;
   testvariable++;   // Here are the Breakpoint that works an show testvariable = 5, what I expected

    any_function();
    
    while (1)
    {
        any_cyclic_function();
    }
}

// Anyinclude.c

void any_function(void)
{
   volatile uint32_t testvariable2 __attribute__((unused)) = 0;
   testvariable2 = 5;
   testvariable2++;       //Here are the Breakpoint with the Message "Could not read memory content for stack variable"

}

I worked several times with Atmel Studio 4 & 6 an the ATMEGA series. But this is my first time with ATSAM.
The optimization level is set to none (-O0)
The debug level is set to maximum (-g3)
I don't have any idea, what I do wrong. Maybe someone knows this problem an can give me a solution.
Thanks in advance.
I goolged the problem, but I didn't find an answer. Someone had the same problem some time ago, but did not get an answer.

Sounds like your variable is optimized out, even though it is marked as volatile. It happens in some compilers as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70380510/non-conforming-optimizations-of-volatile-in-gcc-11-1 The unused is probably not helping too

Microchip's tooling is always so janky.  It doesn't help that embedded debugging is usually janky already.  I work with Microchip parts all day at work, and I just printf debug.  If you have access to a serial port, just do that =]

@Jason it uses gcc for cortex targets

@0___________ It's not the compiler that is a problem.  They use gcc for just about everything.  It's literally everything else that is the problem.

@Eugene Sh: I know, the attribute unused is only to avoid unnessesary warnings.
